# The correct & acceptable phrase to indicate that some papers are very likely to be accepted

Tags: publications, phd, thesis, peer-review

I have several papers that are resubmitted to journals with minor revisions.

I feel they are very much likely to be accepted by the time my actual Ph.D. viva takes place in one month.

But I need to submit my PhD thesis now. I do not want to list those papers as simply "under review". I want to indicate they are very likely to be accepted, as they are resubmitted only with minor revisions.

What is the correct and polite phrase to say the state of these papers?

If you are an examiner, would you be unhappy to see that I indicate some papers are likely to be accepted?

Comment: What about "Minor revision requested"? I *would* be somewhat unhappy if you just told me that those papers are "likely to be accepted" without a good reason why you think so, but saying that you received a "Minor Revision" in the last reviewing round is generally understood as "basically accepted".

Comment: Why has this post been voted as "too broad"? I do not see anything odd with the question.

Comment: Random error exists throughout the peer review process.  Play it safe and simply note the stage of the review process without qualifying it further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stating the status of manuscripts in a thesis should not be an issue. The best way is to phrase their status as expressed by the journal. We see this all the time from "submitted to", "under review in" to "revised with major/minor revision". You cannot state that they are likely to be accepted since that is not your decision and stranger things have happened.

What has to be remembered is that even a paper that has been published can be discussed and criticised so the above information just means to an examiner that someone else, impartial, has possibly commented on the manuscript or that a journal has found it worthy of review.

I would guess most examiners would see a status as additional "evidence" for a basic acceptable quality of the work but would not necessarily affect their judgement, which is personal anyway.